# Getting MissingTokenException when I run the query through JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

I am running the below query using JPA and getting below mentioned exception:

JPA Code :

```
int count = em.createQuery(QueryCollections.getSoldProductUpdateQuery(billGuid).toString()).executeUpdate();
```

Here is the query :

```
Query:  
 UPDATE at_product currentproduct
            JOIN
        (SELECT 
            atbillfields.billeditemguid AS productguid,
                COUNT(*) AS number_of_people_bought,
                SUM(atbillfields.billeditemqty) AS soldquantity
        FROM
            jtbillingtest.at_salesbill atsalesbill
        JOIN jtbillingtest.at_billfields atbillfields ON atsalesbill.billbatchguid = atbillfields.billbatchguid
        WHERE
            atsalesbill.billguid = '41'
        GROUP BY atbillfields.billeditemguid) soldproductdetails ON soldproductdetails.productguid = currentproduct.productguid 
    SET 
        currentproduct.productQuantity = currentproduct.productQuantity - soldproductdetails.soldquantity
```

Exception thrown by jpa.

```
> Exception , line 1, column 34: syntax error at [JOIN]. Internal
> Exception: MissingTokenException(inserted [@-1,0:0='<missing
> SET>',<62>,1:34] at JOIN)     at
> org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1477)
>   at myjavfxapp.dal.ProductDal.updateSoldProducts(ProductDal.java:46)
>   at
> myjavfxapp.controller.BillingController$6.handle(BillingController.java:421)
>   at
```

But if i run this query directly in MySQL server it is running without fail.
Please point out if i missed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPQL and SQL are not the same language. You're trying to execute a SQL query with `executeQuery()`, which expects a JPQL query.

Use `em.createNativeQuery()`.